# R list to string representation

Tags: r

I want to get a string representation of a list, which can be used to recreate a list with the same value.

What I'm searching for is a function like the Python `repr()` function.

```
model = list(name='ugarch', spec=list(garchOrder = c(1, 1)))

str = str_repr(model)

# str should be equal to "list(name='ugarch', spec=list(garchOrder = c(1, 1)))"
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: maybe `dput(model)`?

Comment: you should wrap that in an example usage @NicE and make it an answer.

Comment: @NicE `dput` doesn't *quite* have the behavior OP is looking for, since it writes the string representation to stdout and return a copy of its input instead. But it can be used to write a function like python's `repr()`.

Answer (score 3):

The `dput` function *almost* does what you want: it attempts to deparse an object into an ASCII text representation. However, it's not very suitable for programming: the string representation is written to stdout or a file (default is to write to the console), and the actual output is just an invisible copy of the input:

```
dput(list(x = 1))
## structure(list(x = 1), .Names = "x")
y <- dput(list(x = 1))
## structure(list(x = 1), .Names = "x")
y
## $x
## [1] 1

class(y)
## [1] "list"
```

However, you can use `dput` and `capture.output` to write a function that has the behavior you want:

```
repr <- function(x) {
    y <- capture.output(dput(x))
    paste(y, collapse = '')
}

z <- repr(list(x = 1))
z
## [1] "structure(list(x = 1), .Names = \"x\")"
class(z)
## [1] "character"
```